# Show that (1) $A(S) = \{Ax : x \in S \}$ and (2) $A^{-1}(S) = \{x : Ax \in S \}$ are convex but (1) is not always closed while (2) is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> **Problem definition**:
>
> Show that image of $S$ under $A$, i.e., $A(S) = \{Ax : x \in S \}$ is (a) convex and (b) but not closed *in general* if $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. Also, can we show when $A(S)$ is closed and when it is not?
>
> However, if we consider the preimage $S$ under $A$, i.e., $A^{-1}(S) = \{x : Ax \in S \}$, then it is both closed and convex.
>
> EDIT: $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.
>
> EDIT EDIT: Additionally, assume that $S$ is closed, i.e., $S$ is a closed and convex set.

Comment: $A$ is a linear transformation here? Also, it seems like the exercise should read “$A(S)$ isn’t closed _in general_”. Sometimes $A(S)$ is closed, but it’s not _always_ closed.

Comment: Yes, $A$ is a linear transformation matrix. Aha interesting. Can we show when it is not closed and when it is closed?

Comment: Such conditions should exist. You should edit your post if that’s what you’d like to ask

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(1) I suspect to your proof of convexity. You need to prove that$$\text{if }\quad v_1,v_2\in A(S)\quad\text{ then }\quad \alpha v_1+(1-\alpha )v_2\in A(S)\quad,\quad0\le \alpha \le1$$if $v_1,v_2\in A(S)$ then there exist $x_1,x_2\in S$ such that$$v_1=Ax_1\\v_2=Ax_2$$also $S$ is convex so $\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha )x_2\in S$ which means that $$A(\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha )x_2)\in A(S)$$and $A$ is linear therefore$$A(\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha )x_2)=\alpha Ax_1+(1-\alpha)Ax_2=\alpha v_1+(1-\alpha)v_2\in A(S)$$which completes the proof on convexity.
We prove the following theorem $$\text{A}(S)\text{ is closed if and only if }S\text{ is closed.}$$proof 1: let $S$ be closed. Then every convergent sequence $v_1,v_2,v_3,\cdots \in A(S)$ converges to some $v$ whether in $A(S)$ or not. By definition we have $$v_1=Ax_1\\v_2=Ax_2\\v_3=Ax_3\\.\\.\\.$$since $v_i$s converge and $A$ is linear so the sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots$ is convergent to some $x$  and because S is closed hence $x\in S$ which is equivalent to $Ax\in A(S)$. Therefore the sequence $v_1,v_2,\cdots \in A(S)$ converges to $v=Ax\in A(S)$ and $A(S)$ is closed.
proof 2: let $S$ is not closed and assume by contradiction that $A(S)$ is closed. Therefore there exists some convergent sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3\cdots \in S$ converging to some point outside of $S$. This sequence can be translated to $v_1=Ax_1,v_2=Ax_2,v_3=Ax_3,\cdots \in A(S)$ which is convergent to $v\in A(S)$. Hence the definition $$\exists x\in S\quad,\quad v=Ax$$therefore the sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3\cdots \in S$ is convergent to $x\in S$ which is contradiction. Therefore $A(S)$ is not closed and the proof is complete.
(2) The proof of convexity is simple, but I'm not sure if $A^{-1}(S)$ is always closed. Here is a counterexample. Take $A=I$ and $S$ any convex open set (such as inside the unit ball). Then $A^{-1}(S)=\{x|x\in S\}=S$ which is convex but open.

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction of my attempt and also your answer. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: It is not true though that $A(S)$ is closed if $S$ is closed.  The sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ need not converge.  Of course, if it does converge, then it has to converge to some $x\in S$, since $S$ is closed.  In my example (see my answer), $v_n:=\frac{1}{n}\,Au$ converges to $0$, but its preimage under $A$ in $S$ can be taken to be $x_n=\frac{1}{n}\,u+n\,v$, and $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ do not form a convergent sequence.

Comment: @user550103 hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

(b) I assume that $S$ is a closed convex set; otherwise, an example is too trivial.  I claim that, for a noninvertible nonzero linear transformation $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, there exists a closed convex set $S$ such that $A(S)$ is not closed.  Indeed, we have the following proposition.

> **Proposition.** Let $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear transformation.  Then, for every closed set $S$, the set $A(S)$ is closed if and only if $A=0$ or $A$ is invertible.  (The convexity of $S$ is unnecessary.)

If $A$ is noninvertible and nonzero, then there exists a nonzero vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Av=0$.  Since $A$ is nonzero, there exists a nonzero vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ perpendicular to $v$ with respect to the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Define $$S:=\big\{xu+yv\,\big|\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\text{ and }xy\geq 1\big\}\,.$$  It can be easily seen that $S$ is a convex set.  However, $A(S)=\big\{t\,Au\,|\,t\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\big\}$ obviously is not a closed set (since $0$ is a limit point of $A(S)$ that does not lie in $A(S)$).

If $A$ is zero, then $A(S)=\emptyset$ or $A(S)=\{0\}$, which are closed sets.  If $A$ is invertible, then $m=n$ and $A$ is a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, so $A$ sends closed sets to closed sets (and $A$ sends convex sets to convex sets due to Part (a)).

However, if you have a specific closed set $S$ and you want to determine whether $A(S)$ is also closed, then it is also possible to answer.  First, let $N$ denote the nullspace of $A$.  Then, $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ factors through the canonical projection $\pi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n/N$ via $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^n/N\to\mathbb{R}^m$ sending $v+N\mapsto Av$ for any $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (that is, $A=\alpha\circ\pi$).  Note that $\alpha$ is a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-diffeomorpism from $\mathbb{R}^n/N$ to its image.  Therefore, it suffices to determine whether $\pi(S)$ is a closed set.

Comment: Thank you so much for the nice proof. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you think $A^{-1}(S)$ set is also not closed in general? Mostafa showed an interesting example that if $A^{-1}$ is an identity matrix then this set is not closed...

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, then $A^{-1}(S)$ is a closed set if and only if $S$ is a closed set.  On the other hand, if we don't know whether $A$ is invertible, then we only know that $A^{-1}(S)$ is closed, provided that $S$ is closed.  Your problem statement never assumes that $S$ is a closed set, so I don't know why you would think that $A(S)$ (or $A^{-1}(S)$) should be closed.

Comment: In fact, you never even assumed that $S$ is convex.  Your problem statement is very unclear to begin with, and we the answerers are making guess work here.  You should fix your problem statement to make it clear whether $S$ is convex, and whether $S$ is closed.  Don't let other users read your mind.  I had to make a guess of what you wanted too (see my first sentence: "I assume that $S$ is a closed convex set").

Comment: I am so sorry in missing the assumption that $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. Do I still miss any important assumption?

Comment: And if $S$ is not closed, then $A(S)$ may or may not be a closed set.  It is not a very interesting question if you don't know anything else about $S$ except that it is convex.

Comment: I think my lecturer has got the question from here (Q1): http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt/homework/homework1.pdf . In this exercise, there is no claim whether $S$ is closed!? or do I miss anything? I think my lecturer missed something, On Q1.3, it says that replace convex with closed

Comment: In Question 1 of the pdf file above, it is said that you are to replace "convex" by "closed."  That is,  Part (i) becomes: "Show that If $S$ is ***closed***, then $A(S)$ is ***closed***" (which is not true).  Part (ii) becomes: "Show that If $S$ is ***closed***, then $A^{-1}(S)$ is ***closed***" (this version is true).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that tip in my proof, but I have a question. Let $S=\Bbb R^2$ which is closed, open and complete. Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ then the set $A(S)$ contains all the vectors with their 2nd entry being zero. This set is obviously homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ and we can ascribe each component of $A(S)$ uniquely to each real number. As you know also $\Bbb R$ is closed and complete. Isn't this a counterexample to your first statement you sought to prove?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz  No, this is not a counterexample.  In my proposition, there is a quantifier: ***for all every closed set $S$***.   If $A$ is nonzero and noninvertible, then there very well may be some closed set $S$ such that $A(S)$ is closed, but certainly not all closed sets $S$ satisfy the property that $A(S)$ is closed.  (In fact, there are infinitely many closed sets $S$ such that $A(S)$ is closed.)

Comment: For your example, I take $S:=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}\big|\,xy=1\big\}$.  Then, $A(S)$ consists of vectors of the form $(x,0)$ with $x>0$.  This set $A(S)$ is not a closed set.